# How can I change the name of an image that is being uploaded to my server?

Tags: php

When someone uploads an image to my server, it uploads as the name they have for the image on their computer. I want the image name to become a short number as the name instead of the name, because when someone uploads an image as the same name, it overwrites it.

Here is my script where the names are defined:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {

  $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);

  $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));

  $type = end($sepext);

  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);

  $err = '';
```

Comment: What's wrong with just saving it with a different name?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, depends on which naming convention you wish to have. I.e.: New word(s) added, random number, date_time. The list goes on.

Comment: I just want it to be a random number.

Comment: You could generate a random string of several characters, just like what imgur and Youtube (video id) do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @user2469539 I was faced with the same dilemna a few years ago, due to the default image naming for uploads coming in from iPhone/iPod users, where the name by default is `image.jpg`, thus in the overwriting of anyone else uploading from the same devices. Hence, my creation of the script and I hope it serves you well. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a piece of (working) code I wrote a few years ago, that I still use to this day.

You probably may have to modify it to fit your script as well as the position in the script and the path.

However, I did replace my own original name (`photo`) with your `fileup` name.

Plus there are a few other goodies in there you probably could use, somewhere down the line.

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['fileup']['name'][0];

// should there be spaces in the uploaded file, replace them with an underscore
$file_name = str_replace(" ","_",$file_name);
$random_digit = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);
$new_file_name=$random_digit._.$file_name;
$path1= "./uploads/".$new_file_name;

// you can also use (my original write):
// copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);

move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);

$path_to_file_web = "http://www.example.com/uploads/$new_file_name";
```

The original script that I wrote was used on an older server with an older PHP version.

However, `copy()` will still work.

Comment: You should use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) not `copy()` to put the file into it's final location. This code also makes no consideration for what kinds of names you want to allow, so could leave security holes with cleverly crafted input.

Comment: @IMSoP That works yes thanks. I'll edit my answer with that. My original script was written to take into account something else. Cheers

Comment: @IMSoP I merely answered the OP's original question. Nothing was mentioned in the question in regards to which file types to accept. However, I do agree with what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

i am just add some random string at beginning of file name

```
$new=generate_name(10);
$name=$new.$name;
```

Function generate_name();

```
function generate_name($long){ 
       $cadena="[^A-Z0-9]"; 
       return substr(eregi_replace($cadena, "", md5(rand())) . 
       eregi_replace($cadena, "", md5(rand())) . 
       eregi_replace($cadena, "", md5(rand())), 
       0, $long); 
}
```

and generate this name:

03f396a35902-06-2013.csv
from 02-06-2013.csv file.

Comment: I'm not saying anything bad about your answer, it's a good one, however `eregi_replace` has been deprecated and replaced with `preg_replace`. `eregi_replace` may not run on all servers, depending on the PHP version. Just saying ;-) P.s.: You could also use `str_replace`.

Comment: this is some code i made a few year ago, and i dont update it... tnx :)

Comment: so now i will steal your answer :P

Comment: lol! you're welcome to use it and I hope it serves you well, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you not have to use the name provided when uploading a file, you *shouldn't* do so - like any user input, it is untrusted and could be used as a security hole.

So all you need to do is generate a random image name, and ensure it is not one that you've already used (e.g. by checking with `file_exists()` and using a `do ... while` loop to keep generating random names until that returns false). Then use that as the argument to [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), which is the correct function to use for putting the file into a final location.

If you don't mind too much about the length and format, [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is a good way to generate your filenames, because it is based on the current time so is unlikely to produce collisions.